# get name of emacs application within emacs

Tags: macos, emacs

### Context

I copied Emacs.app and renamed it TerminalEmacs.app so I could access the (emacs) terminal from Alfred by typing "t". This way I keep all my terminal frames/windows in one emacs process (TerminalEmacs.app), and my work in another (Emacs.app).

### Problem

I want like to run some initialization only if the emacs process was launched from TerminalEmacs.app, so i'd like to check the name of the emacs application process from within emacs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could access the environment variable `EMACSPATH`, on a Mac, it contains `Emacs.app` (or whatever the application is called) as part of the path. I guess that you could do something like:

```
(if (string-match "TerminalEmacs\\.app" (getenv "EMACSPATH"))
   ...)
```

Comment: this stopped working (as of Mac 10.9.1 and/or Emacs 24.3.1, if versions are the problem). `(getenv "EMACSPATH")` is `nil`. other suggestions?

Comment: in fact, a few other emacs-specific environment-variables aren't being set (like PWD or EMACSDATA) if that's relevant. even in the original "Emacs.app".

Comment: @samboosalis, apparently, this solution no longer works. However, I just posted another way to accomplish this.

Answer (score 1):

The variable `command-line-args` initially contains the original application name and all arguments. The arguments are later deleted from the list as they are processed, however the application name still is part of the list.

You can do something like:

```
(if (string-match "TerminalEmacs\\.app" (car command-line-args))
    ...)
```